# Create EC2 instance from another instance via command line or dynamically

Tags: amazon-ec2

I want to use power of cloud, where master or main ec2 instance is creating multiple instances based on need and then destroying them.

need to Create multiple instance from same AMI.

I want to know best way to accomplish this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize EC2 APIs for this purpose.

ec2-run-instances (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-RunInstances.html) is a command that allows you to create a new instance from your own (or public) AMI. You can also specify the number of instances you wish to create.

There are also Web Service operation (RunInstances) for this purpose:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-RunInstances.html

Which one to use is up to you. However, I don't think starting a new instance from a master instance is a good practice in AWS. You can rely on Elastic Load Balancing (http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) and Auto Scaling (http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) to scale up/down your server fleet depending on incoming traffic or healthiness of your running instances.

Comment: Agreed, my use case is: i need to download millions of images per user and save it to s3 so i am thinking to create multiple instances at run time based on need and download images for each user.    Let me know if there is any other better approach for the same.